# what is the most comon game development framework

Tags: android, ios, game-engine

i am planing to start game-Dev for smartphones
i have an experience with xna and maya
so what is the best framework to start learning
and is there any ones that can publish for multiple platforms like android, ios .. without rewriting everything
or should i go for opengl ES
and what are the advantages of opengl over the frameworks (if there is an advantage)
so basically i want "a framework to rule them all"

i know that this question might be an-answerable but i just need some start links

Comment: The tool to rule them all depends **highly** on what you want to do. There is no solution that fits everything, so the more specific you can be, the better we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at unity (http://unity3d.com/) or doing it in a basic HTML5 (http://gamesalad.com/creator) lay out ... why or what not ... well I am not the most technical person, but form what I have read this seams to be the best options ...